# GAPI batch request on youtube v3 playlistItems.insert doesnt work as expected

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-js-client

I was playing with v3 Youtube API yesterday and found something unexpected / missing something.

Below code piece is creating a batch request to add multiple playlistItems.insert request and executes them.

```js
const gapiRequest = (playlistId,videoId,i) => gapi.client.request({
    path: '/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet',
    method:'POST',
    body:JSON.stringify({
        snippet: {
            playlistId,
            position:i,
            resourceId:{
                videoId,
                kind: 'youtube#video'
            }
        }
    })
})

let addItemsToList = gapi.client.newBatch();
songs.map((song,i) => {
    addItemsToList.add(
        gapiRequest(playlistId,song.get('id'),i)
    );
})

addItemsToList.then(result => {
    console.log(result)
    debugger;
})
```

I double checked the batch request. As I expected it has 19 (means I'm tryin to add 19 playlist item to playlist) request.

Also it's looks all working fine when I debug result. Batch request returns status 200 (means all playlistItems inserted) for every batch item.

But when it comes to [youtube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHeHlEd7zUAh0zHDwASJ_Nvks4VXbD8gu) I only see 3(sometimes 5-6) song added.

Does anyone have an idea what's going on / what am I missing ?

Comment: Why don't you use `gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.insert` prebuilt method to insert a video in a playlist as described [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript)

Comment: Actually the fn named gapiRequest does the same thing with `gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.insert`. It actually works fine when I request them one by one. But I prefer to send them as batch.